# Задача комивояжера

Tags: c#, алгоритм, структуры-данных, комбинаторика

Как можно реализовать алгоритм задачи комивояжера, используя очередь? Нужно найти исчерпывающим поиском в ширину. Я понимаю как сделать это простым перебором, но так, как в задании, не совсем понимаю. Я не прошу написать весь кода за меня, просто хотелось бы разобраться